# TFS 2013 : Multiple build controller on the same machine

Tags: tfs, build

I wish we could use multiple build controllers on the same machine because we have many team project collections but they're not used at the same time so there's no real performance issue here and most of our build servers are not used for extended period of time. I know it's possible to do this with TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 ([see following post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/configuring-multiple-tfs-build-services-on-one-machine.aspx)) but it's an unsupported feature.

Anyone can tell me if it's now officially supported with TFS 2013, I've not been able to find any useful information about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is still an unsupported feature. This feature would be loudly trompetted should it arrive.

On the chances of this arriving in the TFS 2013 updates, I don't expect it. Maybe with TFS v14 (they're skipping v13) or maybe the version after that?

Make your voice heard on UserVoice:

- http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037679-remove-one-one-binding-between-collection-and-buil
- http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4417771-use-a-build-controller-over-more-than-one-team-pro
- http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3872254-tfs-2012-possibility-to-have-more-than-one-build

---

### Update

A new build system was introduced in TFS 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services. It's agent based. doesn't have Controllers and you can install multiple agents on a single machine.

Agents are grouped in Pools and live at the Server level, allowing you to use them across collections.

Comment: Thanks. As an ALM ranger, what do you think are the chances to get that feature in a near future ?

Comment: A simple and better supported solution may be to just run several VMs on your single machine.