# Cannot create build definition due to build controller not available

Tags: tfsbuild

When trying to create a new build definition for my Team Project, I got the below error.

I check and see that the build controller is running.

How can I get around with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per your other question:

- [Cannot select the TFS build service for more than one team project collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678226/cannot-select-the-tfs-build-service-for-more-than-one-team-project-collection)

This is a known limitation of Team Build. Each Build Controller can only be assigned to one TeamProjectCollection, but you can install multiple Build Controllers (although you can only install one Build Controller on one Machine). So if you need to service multiple Project Collections, you will need to configure multiple Build Controllers.

See also:

- [TFS 2013 : Multiple build controller on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639404/tfs-2013-multiple-build-controller-on-the-same-machine)