# Cannot select the TFS build service for more than one team project collection

Tags: tfs, team-project-collection

As I got the error on `build controller` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677911/cannot-create-build-definition-due-to-build-controller-not-available), I open the `build configuration` in Administrator Console on my TFS Server 2012 server, and go for the property as below snapshot. It seems that we can NOT select the build service for more than one `team project collection`.

Why do we have the option to create multiple `team project collection` while we can build from one of them only?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation of Team Build. Each Build Controller can only be assigned to one TeamProjectCollection, but you can install multiple Build Controllers (although you can only install one Build Controller on one Machine). So if you need to service multiple Project Collections, you will need to configure multiple Build Controllers, meaning multiple Build Servers (machines).

See also:

- [TFS 2013 : Multiple build controller on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639404/tfs-2013-multiple-build-controller-on-the-same-machine)